# Can't run OpenGL on WSL2

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glx

I am trying to run an OpenGL code on WSL2 but am getting the following error on trying to run the executable:

```
GLFW error 65543: GLX: Failed to create context: GLXBadFBConfig
Unable to create GLFW window
```

This is the code I am using to create a window:

```
....
GLFWwindow* initialize() {
      int glfwInitRes = glfwInit();
      if (!glfwInitRes) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to initialize GLFW\n");
         return nullptr;
      }

      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

      GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "InitGL", nullptr, nullptr);
      if (!window) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create GLFW window\n");
         glfwTerminate();
         return nullptr;
      }

      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

      ....
      return window;
   }
   ....

GLFWwindow* window = initialize();
```

I am using VcxSrv as my X server.

Following is from the output for `glxinfo`

```
direct rendering: No (LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT set)
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 940MX/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (4.6.0 NVIDIA 457.30)
```

Comment: Because of `direct rendering: No` your OpenGL version is stuck at 1.4 [see also](https://community.khronos.org/t/opengl-version-is-forced-to-1-4-but-card-can-support-4-6-0/104868), so version 3.2 features will not work for you.

Comment: I have no idea what you need to do on WSL2 to get direct rendering, let's see if someone else knows.

Answer (score 18):

The following fix worked for me.

As [@dratenik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14215102/dratenik) mentioned above, the problem persists because of `direct rendering: No`. To solve this, do the following:

In the bashrc/zshrc file, add the following:

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0
```

Or you could just remove `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` line from your bashrc/zshrc file if you have added it.

Then, start a new instance of VcxSrv with and unselect the **Native opengl** box on the Extra Settings page, and select the **Disable access control** box.
[image: VcxSrv Extra Settings]

After doing this, direct rendering should be turned on, and you should get the following on running `glxinfo`:

```
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
...
```

Comment: FTR, now that WSL2 lets you run X clients (also with GL) natively (no more 3rd-party X servers, yay!), this was exactly what I need to set (apart from `DISPLAY=:0`) for my X app to actually start working finally.